# Gmail randomly exposes gmail address

Tags: gmail

I have various email addresses set up under Gmail. I have checked 'Treat as Alias' and also checked 'Reply from the same address the message was sent to'. Despite this I find that Gmail will randomly expose my user@gmail.com address when sending mail, or when I reply to mail sent to one of my pseudonymous addresses.

Have other people had this problem?

Is there something else I need to do to get Gmail to secure my email addresses?

Is there another service I should consider that has better integrity with regard to this issue?

Comment: This probably belongs on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @GSerg You may be right. Do you know if there's a way for me to transfer my question over to webapps?

Comment: You delete it here and post there.